# shared_ptr and cyclic references

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, cyclic-reference

I was trying with the cyclic references for `boost::shared_ptr`, and devised following sample:

```
class A{ // Trivial class
public:
    i32 i;
    A(){}
    A(i32 a):i(a){}
    ~A(){
        cout<<"~A : "<<i<<endl;
    }
};

shared_ptr<A> changeI(shared_ptr<A> s){
    s->i++;
    cout<<s.use_count()<<'\n';

    return s;
}

int main() {

    shared_ptr<A> p1 = make_shared<A>(3);
    shared_ptr<A> p2 = p1;
    shared_ptr<A> p3 = p2;
    shared_ptr<A> p4 = p3;

    p1 = p4; // 1) 1st cyclic ref.
    cout<<p1.use_count()<<'\n';

    p1 = changeI(p4); // 2) 2nd cyclic ref.

    cout<<p1.use_count()<<'\n';

//  putchar('\n');
    cout<<endl;
}
```

which outputs

```
4
5
4

~A : 4
```

Is it that I've misinterpreted the cyclic references mentioned for `boost::shared_ptr`? Because, I expected different output thinking of indirect references to `p1` after comments `1)` and `2)`.
So this code doesn't require `boost::weak_ptr`! So what are the cyclic references where `weak_ptr`s would be required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the middle result of 5 is due to passing shared pointer object by value to function leading to new copy of shared pointer as s

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you have misinterpreted this. In your example, all the pointers are pointing to the same object, not forming any cycles.

The assignment of p4 to p2 is a no-op, since those pointers were already equal to begin with.

Here's an example with real cyclic references, maybe that will clear things up:

```
struct A
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> ptr;
};

void main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> x=std::make_shared<A>();
  std::shared_ptr<A> y=std::make_shared<A>();

  x->ptr = y; // not quite a cycle yet
  y->ptr = x; // now we got a cycle x keeps y alive and y keeps x alive
}
```

You can even make this even simpler:

```
void main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> x=std::make_shared<A>();

  x->ptr = x; // never die! x keeps itself alive
}
```

In both examples, the objects in the shared_ptrs are never destructed, even after you leave main.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Now in your example, will `x` die when process ends (in Linux - I am using Ubuntu 10.04), or it depends on OS whether it lives till reboot?

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking that's the OS's job. All the OSs I know do it though. Some embedded OSs might not.

Comment: Ok, so cycles would be formed when some object having a member pointer is directly/indirectly pointing to itself. Are there any other scenarios? Please do tell.

Comment: No, that's pretty much the definition of a cycle; an object pointing directly or indirectly to itself, thus never losing that one reference.

Comment: Will the use_count() of x and y decrease from 2 to 1 when main returns?

Comment: @Itjax is'nt `ptr` will get destruct while calling destructor of `A` so it will decrease reference count to 0 and it will get free. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: @EmptyData The destructor is only called once the reference count is already 0.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to point out: the reason why the second line of the output is a `5` and not a `4` is not because of the `s->i++` increase, but because the `shared_ptr<A> s` parameter is being passed by value.

Upon calling

```
p1 = changeI(p4); // 2) 2nd cyclic ref.
```

`p4` will be copied to yet another `shared_pointer`, temporarily increasing the `use_count` by one during the scope of the function.

Maybe I'm playing captain obvious here (;