# why memory leak when use circular reference in boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, boost-smart-ptr

in the follow code memory leak happened, I have my doubt about that. in the test() fun:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>

class parent;
class children;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<parent> parent_ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<children> children_ptr;

class parent
{
public:
    ~parent() { std::cout <<"destroying parent\n"; }

public:
    children_ptr children;
};

class children
{
public:
    ~children() { std::cout <<"destroying children\n"; }

public:
    parent_ptr parent;
};

void test()
{
    parent_ptr father(new parent());
    children_ptr son(new children);

    father->children = son;// parent_ptr_count=1, children_ptr_count=2
    son->parent = father;// parent_ptr_count=2, children_ptr_count=2
   //1,2,3 See the note below
}

void main()
{
    std::cout<<"begin test...\n";
    test();
    std::cout<<"end test.\n";
}
```

1. // childern_ptr pop from stack, I think the childern_ptr_count-- and parent_ptr_count--
2. // parent_ptr pop from stack, I think the childern_ptr_count-- and parent_ptr_count--
3. // but in fact, it didn't do that, why?

I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Because C++ doesn't have a grand framework that can detect circular references. Each shared pointer operates individually and can only attempt to deallocate the pointee when itself is deallocated first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is exactly the scenario in this example: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/10/19/circular-references.aspx

This is a cyclic reference, and the solution is to have one of the pointers be a weak pointer. Although the article is for C++11's implementation of shared and weak pointers, boost also has a weak pointer for the exact same reason.

Answer (score 0):

When `son` is destroyed, the reference count for the `children` object goes down, but the reference count for the `parent` object does not, because the `children` object that contains the `parent_ptr` was not destroyed (because its reference count is 1, not 0).

Likewise, when `father` is destroyed, the reference count for the `parent` object goes down, but the reference count for the `children` object does not, because the `parent` object that contains the `children_ptr` was not destroyed (because its reference count is 1, not 0).

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers suggest, you have created [a circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338226/shared-ptr-and-cyclic-references).

Here's a solution. When you have pointers pointing to each other, it can often be useful to use a `weak_ptr`. What this does is makes a pointer that you can turn into a `shared_ptr`, and when it's not a `shared_ptr` it doesn't increment the reference count, therefore allowing the objects to be destroyed.

Here's an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>

class parent;
class children;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<parent> parent_ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<children> children_ptr;

typedef boost::weak_ptr<parent> parent_weak_ptr;
typedef boost::weak_ptr<children> children_weak_ptr;

class parent
{
public:
    ~parent() { std::cout <<"destroying parent\n"; }

public:
    children_weak_ptr children;
};

class children
{
public:
    ~children() { std::cout <<"destroying children\n"; }

public:
    parent_weak_ptr parent;
};

void test()
{
    parent_ptr father(new parent());
    children_ptr son(new children);

    father->children = son;// parent_ptr_count=1, children_ptr_count=1
    son->parent = father;// parent_ptr_count=1, children_ptr_count=1
}

void main()
{
    std::cout<<"begin test...\n";
    test();
    std::cout<<"end test.\n";
}
```

With this code, the children and parent are destroyed, AND they can access each other using the `lock()` function on the `weak_ptr` to turn it into a `shared_ptr`. Here's some docs:

`boost::weak_ptr` [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm)

`std::weak_ptr` [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)