# C++11 using smart pointers but get invalid pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, coredump

I'm using unique_ptr and shared_ptr in this C++ assignment, the code works fine until the end it says

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I can't figure out how does it happen.

The code parses file "resource.txt" and construct a graph. 
Each word is a node, and each line implies dependency between two words.
resource.txt

```
handgun bullets
bullets ore
bombs ore
turret bullets
```

Below is my output and code:

output of ./main

```
adding edge: 'handgun' --> 'bullets'
adding edge: 'bullets' --> 'ore'
adding edge: 'bombs' --> 'ore'
adding edge: 'turret' --> 'bullets'
graph now has nodes:
bombs-->
        ore
ore-->
turret-->
        bullets
handgun-->
        bullets
bullets-->
        ore
=======
graph destructor
destructor of node: bombs
destructor of node: turret
destructor of node: handgun
destructor of node: bullets
destructor of node: turret
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

you can see that each destructor was called, and I am using smart pointers but I still got invalid pointer error.

main.cpp

```
#include "graph.h"
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unique_ptr<graph> g(new graph("./resource.txt"));
    g->dispay();
    cout << "=======" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

graph.h

```
#ifndef Tan_Li_Graph_Head_
#define Tan_Li_Graph_Head_

#include "node.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class graph
{
  private:
    /* data */
  public:
    unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<node>> nodes;
    graph(string resourceFileName);
    bool addEdge(string from, string to);
    void delNode(string name);
    void dispay();
    ~graph();
};

#endif
```

graph.cpp

```
#include "graph.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

graph::graph(string fileName)
{
    ifstream file(fileName);
    string str;
    while (getline(file, str))
    {

        if (str.back() == '\r')
        {
            str.pop_back();
        }

        auto space_loc = str.find(" ");
        string from = str.substr(0, space_loc);
        string to = str.substr(space_loc + 1);
        this->addEdge(from, to);
    }
}

bool graph::addEdge(string from, string to)
{
    cout << "adding edge: '" << from << "' --> '" << to << "\'" << endl;

    if (this->nodes.count(from) == 0)
    {
        shared_ptr<node> node_from = make_shared<node>(from);
        this->nodes.insert(make_pair(from, node_from));
    }

    if (this->nodes.count(to) == 0)
    {
        shared_ptr<node> node_to = make_shared<node>(to);
        this->nodes.insert(make_pair(to, node_to));
    }

    return this->nodes[from]->addChild(this->nodes[to]);
}

void graph::delNode(string name)
{
    auto node_to_del = this->nodes[name];

    for (auto parent : node_to_del->parents)
    {
        parent.second->delChild(node_to_del);
    }

    for (auto child : node_to_del->children)
    {
        node_to_del->delChild(child.second);
    }
}

void graph::dispay()
{
    cout << "graph now has nodes: " << endl;
    for (auto node_to_display : this->nodes)
    {
        // cout << node_to_display.second->name << ": " << (node_to_display.second->useable ? "usable" : "NOT usable")
        //      << " ;" << endl;
        cout << node_to_display.second->name << "-->" << endl;
        for (auto child : node_to_display.second->children)
        {
            cout << '\t' << child.second->name << endl;
        }
    }
}

graph::~graph()
{
    cout << "graph destructor" << endl;
}
```

node.h

```
#ifndef Tan_Li_Node_Head_
#define Tan_Li_Node_Head_
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
  private:
    /* data */
  public:
    string name;
    bool useable;
    unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<node>> children;
    unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<node>> parents;
    node(string name);
    bool addChild(shared_ptr<node> child);
    bool addChild(string name);
    bool delChild(shared_ptr<node> child);
    bool delChild(string name);
    ~node();
};

#endif
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

node::node(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->useable = true;
}

bool node::addChild(shared_ptr<node> child)
{
    string child_name = child->name;

    if (child_name.compare(this->name) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Node " << this->name << " can't add itself to children" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (this->children.count(child_name) == 0)
    {
        this->children.insert(make_pair(child_name, child));
        child->parents.insert(make_pair(this->name, this));
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Node " << child_name << " is already in the child of node " << this->name << endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool node::addChild(string name)
{
    if (name.compare(this->name) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Node " << this->name << " can't add itself to children" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    shared_ptr<node> child = make_shared<node>(name);
    this->addChild(child);
}

bool node::delChild(shared_ptr<node> child)
{
    string child_name = child->name;

    if (this->children.count(child_name) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Node " << child_name << " is NOT the child of node " << this->name << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        child->parents.erase(this->name);
        this->children.erase(child_name);
    }

    this->useable = false;

    return true;
}

bool node::delChild(string name)
{
    if (this->children.count(name) == 0)
    {

        cout << "Node " << name << " is NOT the child of node " << this->name << endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        this->children[name]->parents.erase(this->name);
        this->children.erase(name);
    }

    this->useable = false;

    return true;
}

node::~node()
{
    cout << "destructor of node: " << this->name << endl;
}
```

Comment: `for (auto parent : node_to_del->parents) { parent.second->delChild(node_to_del); }` This is a problem - `delChild` has a side effect of modifying `node_to_del->parents` just as you are iterating over it. Chances are, the program is using an invalidated iterator, and therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: There must be more to the code you are actually running than the code you've shown. You are creating circular dependencies - just letting `graph` die won't automatically destroy nodes as they all refer to each other. You are likely doing something in `~graph()` that you are not showing.

Comment: Code Review: graph::delNode(string name) should first check if the node exists before trying to delete it. The operator [] will create an empty one (nullptr) if it did not exist, which will cause "node_to_del->parents" to crash (this is not your issue, but worth fixing)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely this line:

```
    child->parents.insert(make_pair(this->name, this));
```

What you are doing is implicitly creating a `shared_ptr` from  `this` pointer.

See [this](https://ideone.com/UfjdTH) for a smaller repro of your problem.

`shared_ptr` is an unbreakable vow. Once a pointer is managed by a `shared_ptr` its lifecycle may not be controlled by any another class/wrapper.
The memory for `this` pointer was already created and hence is managed by a different instance of `shared_ptr`. By (implicitly) creating another instance of `shared_ptr` using `this` you are breaking the contract.

There are several ways to fix the problem. One way would be to keep raw pointers for any **backedges** (for example raw pointer for parents). That way a parent controls the cycle of the child. The other way is to use

```
unordered_map<string, weak_ptr<node>> parents;
```

You will have to derive `node` from [enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and then do:

```
    child->parents.insert(make_pair(this->name, weak_from_this()));
```

[weak_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/weak_from_this)

Note that you can keep using `shared_ptr` for both parent and child, but then it would be [circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338226/shared-ptr-and-cyclic-references) and you would be leaking memory.